# How to use the loading black screen control in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm not asking for the full implementation here.

I'm asking because I don't even know what it is called, if somebody could at least tell me the
class I can work with that.

thanks

[image: Photo]

Comment: It is called "Heads Up Display" HUD. Just get the mbprogresshud from github and call it a day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in class for this. However, it can be accomplished using a UIWindow and some views. You should browse http://cocoacontrols.com, they have quite a few open-source versions of this.

For example:

MBProgressHUD: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mbprogresshud

DejalActivityView: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dejalactivityview

MMProgressHUD: https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMProgressHUD

Comment: Updated with links to examples.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a partly transparent UIView with black background and a corner radius of about 15, containing an activity indicator and a label. You can create it in a .xib for easy layout and then load it as needed.

Comment: thanks, I figure that, but there are some many apps using the same visual concept that I want to check if there is a control that provides that, instead of possibly reinventing the wheel